# Node pg update multiple rows in one query (error: operator does not exist: text = integer)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I have the following query:

```js
UPDATE test_schema.test_table as t SET
  test_row_value2 = c.test_row_value2
FROM (values
  ($1, $2, $3), ($1, $4, $5)
) as c(id, test_row_value1, test_row_value2)
WHERE c.id = t.id
  AND c.test_row_value1 = t.test_row_value1
RETURNING *
```

My parameters are the following:

```js
[
  72,
  'table_name',
  'test_table',
  'database_name',
  'test_database'
]
```

When I run the query using node pg (version 8.7.3), I get the following error:

```
error: operator does not exist: text = integer
```

From my testing, I figured out it's due to the following lines:

```js
test_row_value2 = c.test_row_value2
c.id = t.id
c.test_row_value1 = t.test_row_value1
```

If I parameterize the right side of the above lines, I don't get the error but nothing gets updated either. I ran the query with hardcoded values in PGAdmin and the query works fine and everything updates correctly. What am I doing wrong in node pg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change this part of the query:

```
c.id = t.id
```

to the following:

```
c.id = t.id::int
```

Notice the `::int` part. I'm not sure why node pg requires the cast but everything seems to be working fine now.